# MERGE TVP + sum the column while updating a record

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, upsert, table-valued-parameters

Source Table

```
Id, Name, hits
1   A     10    
1   A     20
1   A     30
2   A     10
```

Target Table

```
Id, Name, hits
1   A     NULL
```

After Merge

```
Id, Name, hits
1   A     60
2   A     10
```

is the above possible ? using Merge statement ?

Comment: Hi Naveen and welcome to the community. I'm not sure I understand the question, how is the "target table" being used here? This seems more like a "group by Id, Name and summarize the hits per (Id, Name) combination". Where does the merge come into the picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
MERGE     targetTable AS [pi]
USING     ( 
               SELECT id,name,sum(hits) as hits from sourcetable
               GROUP BY id,name
          ) AS src (id,name,hits) ON src.id= [pi].id and scr.name=pi.name
WHEN      MATCHED 
               THEN UPDATE SET [pi].hits= src.hits
WHEN      NOT MATCHED 
               THEN INSERT values (src.id, src.name,hits)
```